# How can I connect the output of a C program to a python program at runtime

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a C program that is generating live data and I am trying to pipe the data to a python program so that I can process it and plot it at run-time.

I can save the output of C program to a file and then read it into python but I want to do it at run-time. Can someone please tell me how can it be done.

Comment: On Unix-like systems you can simply connect standard output of C program and standard input of Python program. Another method would be using sockets, or a named pipe.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Well i already tried to do that and that's what i want to do but it didn't work. I referred to this post 'https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61197/read-c-output-in-python?answertab=active#tab-top' but it did not work. Can you please give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the simplest ways to do this:

1. Make your C program print its output on `stdout`. This is the standard stream which is used by `printf()`.
2. Make your python program read its input from `stdin`. This is the standard stream which is used by `input()`.
3. Connect both programs on the command line with the pipe symbol `|` like this:

   ```
   c-program | python script.py
   ```

Note that there are more ways to make two programs communicate. And there are more ways to write to `stdout` and to read from `stdin`.

The method described works on all major operating systems.

One of its biggest advantages is that you can develop each part independent from the other and test it on its own. In example, you can pipe the output of the C program into a file to check later. Similarly you can pipe the input of this or any other file into the python script.

Comment: I have already tried this but it didn't work. My C program is running a loop that is printing data to standard output continuously . 

./rf_receiver | read_rf.py

read_rf.py 
    >>>while True:
        >>>    read = input()
        >>>    print(read)

Comment: OK, HOW did it not work?

Comment: Sorry but the code indentation is not working for some reason.

Comment: We can't format code in comments. Comments are just that, comments. ;-)

Comment: Hey, now this will sound strange but it is working now. :|
But thanks for the help. Initially it was giving me an error on the first input it was reading but now it is working flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is using the [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) module as following:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    print(line.rstrip())
```

This loop will process every input line from `stdin`.

An then you could run something like

```
cat data.csv | python r.py
```

Comment: I want to do it on run-time so using a file will not be helpful.

Comment: Did you read the docs? `This module implements a helper class and functions to quickly write a loop over standard input`. the cat command was just one example on how to generate content to send to another process (the python one) to stdin